# Install Pytorch for only inference time

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, production-environment

I have already make some research but could not find any useful information. Is it possible to install something like mini pytorch just for load a pre-trained model and call `prediction` method?

Entire PyTorch library size is too big, so I would like to prevent on this issue.

Does anyone have idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For production you need to use `libtorch` and the whole package is around 160MB compressed I guess.
You ship the `Dll`s that your application requires and at the very minimum I guess it could be around 170-200 MBs if you only use the `torch.dll`
And there is not a pytorch mini or anything like that as far as I know.